# I have a list of variables and a function. How would I create a loop to get this function to run through these variables?

Tags: python

let's say I have a list and a function:

```
list = [var1,var2,var3...var14]
run_data_for_var1 = streamdata(var1, messages_var1)
```

How would I create a loop to get this function to run from var1 to var14? Hoping for this end result:

```
run_data_for_var1 = streamdata(var1, messages_var1)
run_data_for_var2 = streamdata(var2, messages_var2)
run_data_for_var3 = streamdata(var3, messages_var3)
....
run_data_for_var14 = streamdata(var14, messages_var14)
```

Edit: Something I should have mentioned was that messages_var is a list of functions. When entering messages_var into the terminal, I would get:

```
<function main.messages_var1(msg)>, 
<function main.messages_var2(msg)>, 
<function main.messages_var3(msg)>, 
<function main.messages_var4>
```

Comment: where are messages_var variables defined?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Each messages_var has already been defined in separate functions.

Comment: Why not just have everything in lists to begin with? A list for all the `var`s, a list for all the `messages_var`s, and then produce a `run_data_for_var`s list.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Let me try out these solutions. Will be back soon.

Comment: Now try again i have updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have tons of similar variables it is probably better to use a list. You already have `var1`, `var2`, `var2`... in a list. Do the same thing for the `messages_var` variables. Then you can use this code:

```py
run_vars = list(map(lambda args: streamdata(*args), zip(var_list, messages_list)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just ran the code. I'm getting a typeerror: map() must have at least two arguments.

Comment: I should have specified that messages_var is a list of functions. So when putting messages_var into the terminal, we get <function main.messages_var1(msg)>, <function main.messages_var2(msg)>, <function main.messages_var3(msg)>, <function main.messages_var4>

Comment: Can confirm the code now works. And its much cleaner solution as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [var1,var2,var3...var14]
message = [messages_var1,messages_var2,messages_var3...messages_var14]
run_data_for_all = []
for i in range(len(list)):
   run_data_for_all.append(streamdata(list[i], message[i]))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I ran the code and received a "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: have you initialized the variables that are in `list`and `message`

Comment: Yes I have. Actually I think my request is a bit more complicated. When typing 'message' list into the terminal, it returns as:     (<function __main__.messages_var1(msg)>,
 <function __main__.messages_var2(msg)>,
 <function __main__.messages_var3(msg)>,
 <function __main__.messages_var4>)

Comment: I should have notified that messages is a list of functions. Will this still work?

Comment: I have not check it, try and do tell me

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. :) I'm new to this site, how do I star this answer?

Comment: if my answer solve your problem then mark it as your solution

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

`exec` built-in function can help you

```py
list = [var1,var2,var3...var14]
run_data_for_var1 = streamdata(var1, messages_var1)

for _ in range(len(list)):
    exec(f"run_data_for_var{str(_+1)} = streamdata(list[{str(_)}], messages_var{str(_+1)}")

# then you can access run_data_for_var1, 2, 3, 4, ...
```

Comment: If you don’t need to use exec, don’t.